# Study of supercell after creating vacuum

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, software-input-file-request

For studying a bulk supercell, after creating some vacuum in it, I'm confused about how to relax it.

With VASP, I can do relaxation using `NSW = 0` and `ISIF` tag 2 or 3.
Alternatively, I could set `NSW=100` and with some value for `ISIF` (not sure what would be best).

A third option is to first relax the supercell, then after creating a vacuum, it is should be fine to select `ISIF=0` for relaxation.

I am not sure which one of these is the best option or whether there is a better alternative.

Comment: Please watch the spaces in your INCAR file. It might only concern some versions of VASP, but I burned myself pretty badly with the INCAR file when I started doing calculations, because the entries were not read correctly. To be on the safe side, always include a space before and after the ``=`` (write ``NSW = 100`` instead of ``NSW=100``), otherwise the code may turn to default values instead of the specified ones. And do not use tabs!

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this useful information.

Answer (score 7):

The common feature of a surface is that interlayer distance changes near the surface. For relaxation of atom and calculating surface energy in vasp `ISIF=2` and `NSW=100`  is correct option.